# Seam 3 tutorial, Spring 3 + Seam 3 integration

Tags: java, spring, seam, spring-3, seam3

I wasn't able to find a `decent Seam 3 tutorial`. It kind of nice that now Seam is spread in modules but the official documentation is slightly vague and weak... Covers all modules, describes each modules but nothing concrete, how to put them together, how to develop an entire application with Seam 3 or at least `some Spring integration`.

Do you know any `Seam 3 tutorials` or even books? Have you heard if there are plans of a new Seam In Action book?

Answer (score 0):

because of new version there isn't more tutorial but maybe this link helps you:
http://seamframework.org/Community/LinksToExternalCDIAndWeldDocumentation